# Window.event target on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, d3.js, events, dom-events

I have this code that does not work with Firefox:

```
button.attr("name", i).on("click",function() {
    var e = window.event;
    var target = (e.target) ? e.target: e.srcElement;
            alert(target.name);
});
```

I think the problem is in the event but I don't know how to fix it.

The error message is:

> [14:59:18.721] e is undefined @ http‍://127.0.0.1:8080/Tesi/javascript/Home.js:4202

Comment: @Jonathan de M. excuse me. I forgotted! edited!

Comment: Not really an answer, but the scope of your function will be the button element itself, so you could replace the whole event.target section with either the jQuery `$(this).attr('name')` or raw JavaScript `this.getAttribute('name')`

Comment: @steveukx: if you answer the question I will give you the correct answer because it works.

Comment: Thanks, I've added it as an answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attaching a click handler in that way will result in the scope of the function being set to the button element itself. You could therefore replace the whole event.target section with either the jQuery:

```
$(this).attr('name');
```

or raw JavaScript:

```
this.getAttribute('name');
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use parameter e.g

```
button.attr("name", i).on("click",function(e) {
   var target = (e.target) ? e.target: e.srcElement;
        alert(target.name);
});
```

**More Info**

```
$("#dataTable tbody tr").on("click", function(event){
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

according to: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: same problem: e is undefined

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass e as a parameter.

```
button.attr("name", i).on("click",function(e) {
    var target = (e.target) ? e.target: e.srcElement;
            alert(target.name);
});
```

Léon

Comment: does not work. If I pass e as a parameter do I have to cancel var e=?

Comment: Changed it , also , are you using jQuery 1.6 ? Because .attr() will return undefined if the attribute isn't correctly set.